# How can I plot multiple plots in a for loop with warnings?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, png

My code's structure (just an example) is basically like this:

```
xs <- c("a","b")
for(x in xs)
{
png(filename = paste(x,".png",sep="")
ggplot()
dev.off()
}
```

When I just run the code inside the loop separately, it yields a png file perfectly, but in Rstudio it has some warnings. But when I run the whole loop together, the png files turn blank. Simply using `options(warn=-1)` to suppress the warnings doesn't help.

What can I do to suppress the warning and make the loop work?

Comment: Use `ggsave()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
xs <- c("a","b")
for(x in xs)
{
p <- ggplot()
ggsave(p,file=paste(x,".png",sep=""))

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the first time I have solved a problem so quickly :)